# How to Determine Underlying Template Type of Template Parameter That Inherits From a Class Template?

Tags: c++, templates

This has probably been asked and answered before, but I haven't been able to figure out the search terms to find it. Here is some code to show my problem (intended as pseudo code...ask for clarification if needed).

Image.h:

```
template <class T>
class Image
{
    public:
        // Return pointer to data.
        T* GetValues(); 

        std::vector<T> data_;

};

template <class T>
T* Image<T>::GetValues()
{
    return &data_[0];
}
```

SpecialImage.h

```
class SpecialImage : public Image<float>
{

}
```

Stack.h

```
template<class T>
class Stack
{
    public:

        void NegateAllImageValues();

        std::vector<T> stackOfImages_;
};

template <class T>
void Stack::NegateAllImageValues()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < stackOfImages_.size(); ++i)
    {
        // Type L should be float if T=SpecialImage, but how to get?
        L* imageValues = stackOfImages_.at(i).GetValues(); 

        // Loop over values and multiply by -1.0.
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
{
    // Create stack of SpecialImages.
    Stack<SpecialImage> myStack; 

    // Create special image and add some data.
    SpecialImage mySpecialImage; 
    mySpecialImage.data_.push_back(1.0f);
    mySpecialImage.data_.push_back(2.0f);
    mySpecialImage.data_.push_back(3.0f);

    // Add special image to stack.
    myStack.stackOfImages_.push_back(mySpecialImage);

    // Negate all values in all SpecialImages in the stack.
    myStack.NegateAllImageValues();

}
```

My question is how to know the type L in Stack::NegateAllImageValues? I realize I could write a method Image::NegateAllValues and call that from Stack::NegateAllImageValues, but I want to know if there is a way to get the type L at the Stack level. I think I could add an additional template parameter to the function Stack::NegateAllImageValues like

```
template <class T, class L>
void Stack::NegateAllImageValues()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < stackOfImages_.size(); ++i)
    {
        // Type L should be float if T=SpecialImage, but how to get?
        L* imageValues = stackOfImages_.at(i).GetValues(); 

        // Loop over values and multiply by -1.0.
    }
}
```

but then the type L is not forced to match the underlying template type of Image.

Is there an inherent design flaw here? Is there a way to get type L at the stack level?

Comment: Capture the type by adding:  `using valueType = T;` to `Image`

Comment: There's also `auto`, but yeah, `Image` should have that type alias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classic way to do this is to put a typedef/alias in your `Image` class, something like

```
template <typename T>
class Image {
public:
    typedef T value_type;

    // Other stuff
};
```

Then later in your `Stack::NegateAllImageValues()` method, you can say

```
template <class T>
void Stack::NegateAllImageValues()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < stackOfImages_.size(); ++i)
    {
        typename T::value_type* imageValues = stackOfImages_.at(i).GetValues(); 

        // Loop over values and multiply by -1.0.
    }
}
```

These kinds of typedefs are used by basically every template class in the standard library: for example, `std::vector<T>` contains (among others) a member typedef `value_type` which is an alias for `T`.

An alternative in C++11 and newer is to use `auto` instead, for example:

```
template <class T>
void Stack::NegateAllImageValues()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < stackOfImages_.size(); ++i)
    {
        auto* imageValues = stackOfImages_.at(i).GetValues(); 

        // Loop over values and multiply by -1.0.
    }
}
```

[Plain `auto` would work just as well as `auto*`, but I prefer the latter as it makes clear that you're expecting a pointer type.]

Finally, in C++11 you could use `decltype` to get the return type of `GetValues()`:

```
template <class T>
void Stack::NegateAllImageValues()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < stackOfImages_.size(); ++i)
    {
        using value_type = decltype(stackOfImages_.at(i).GetValues());
        value_type imageValues = stackOfImages_.at(i).GetValues(); 

        // Loop over values and multiply by -1.0.
    }
}
```

Although this doesn't really gain you anything over `auto`.